# PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: parameters, invalidation

I have a problem when I try to update data into mysql database using PHP PDO.

for all of them, please give me the knowledge to resolve this issue.

thank you

Form_siswa.php

if($_GET['action']=='edit'){

```
                $id = (int) $_GET['id'];
                $data = $siswa->edit($id);

                    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

                        $POST = array( 'id'=> $id
                                       ,'no_induk' => $_POST['noinduk']
                                       ,'nisn' =>$_POST['nis_nasional']
                                       ,'first_name' =>$_POST['first']
                                       ,'last_name' =>$_POST['last']
                                       ,'nick' =>$_POST['nm_panggil']
                                       //,'temp_lahir' =>$_POST['tmp_lahir_siswa']
                                       //,'tgllhr' =>$_POST['tgllhir']
                                       //,'j_kel' =>$_POST['j_kel']
                                       //,'agama_siswa' =>$_POST['agama_siswa']
                                       //,'warganegara' =>$_POST['warganegara']
                                       //,'anakKe' =>$_POST['anakKe']
                                       //,'stat_kel' =>$_POST['stat_kel']
                                       //,'tgl_aktif' =>$_POST['tgl_aktif']
                                       //,'almt_siswa' =>$_POST['almt_siswa']
                                       //,'nm_ayah' =>$_POST['nm_ayah']
                                       //,'nm_ibu' =>$_POST['nm_ibu']
                                       //,'job_ayah' =>$_POST['job_ayah']
                                       //,'tlp_rmh' =>$_POST['tlp_rmh']
                                       //,'hp_ortu' =>$_POST['hp_ortu']
                                       //,'almt_ortu' =>$_POST['almt_ortu']
                                      );

                        $simpan = $siswa->udpate_siswa($POST);   

                        if($simpan>0){
                            $suksess = '<div class="alert alert-success">
                                       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                                       <h4>Suskse!</h4>
                                        data Berhasil di Update
                                       <ediv>';
                        }else{
                             $suksess = '<div class="alert alert-success">
                                       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                                       <h4>GAGAL......!</h4>
                                        Update Data Gagal....
                                       <ediv>';
                        } 
                    } 
            ?>
```

class siswa.php

function udpate_siswa($data){

```
    $sql = "UPDATE tb_siswa SET no_induk=:no_induk, nisn=:nisn, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, nick=:nick  WHERE id=:id";

    $noinduk=$data['no_induk'];
    $nis_nasional = $data['nisn'];
    $first= $data['first_name'];
    $last= $data['last_name'];
    $nm_panggil= $data['nick'];
    $id=$data['id'];

    try {
        $pdo = Database::connect();
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql); 
    $stmt->bindParam('no_induk',$noinduk);  
    $stmt->bindParam('nisn',$nis_nasional); 
    $stmt->bindParam('first_name',$first);
    $stmt->bindParam('last_name',$last);
    $stmt->bindParam('nick',$nm_panggil);
    $stmt->bindParam('id',$id); 

    print_r($data);
    $stmt->execute();
    $rowcount = $stmt->rowCount();
    return $rowcount; 
    $stmt->closeCursor();
    $pdo=Database::disconnect;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        //echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
        echo "\nPDOStatement::errorInfo():\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
no_induk=:no_induk, nisn=:nisn, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, nick=:nick  WHERE id=:id
```

You forgot the colons next to **first_name** and **last_name** parameters.

Then, when you bind the parameters to the values, again don't forget the colons :

```
$stmt->bindParam(':no_induk',$noinduk);
```